# ntpdate not updating system time in XenServer VM

Tags: debian, xen, time, ntpdate, date

We have a Debian webserver that I am trying to use ntpdate to keep the time in sync.

When I run

```
ntpdate ntp0.cs.mu.oz.au
```

I receive

```
16 Sep 10:55:36 ntpdate[21626]: step time server 128.250.36.2 offset 318.914011 sec
```

With no errors, which should be a good thing, I think...

When I check the time again though, it's not changed.

I am also unable to set the time manually using

```
date --set 11:00:00
```

So I have a feeling there are other issues.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Update**

Sorry for the bum steer guys, this machine is a XenServer VM, which I managed to forget.

After updating the Host clock, the VM time is now correct.

Thanks for your replies.
Thanks.

Comment: Not related to the original request, but... note that ntp0.cs.mu.oz.au has now been discontinued and stopped responding to queries. I suggest using au.pool.ntp.org instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been through this before.

Try (on domU):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock
```

and try updating the time again.

Answer (score 1):

Did the time change when you set the new time using date?

Try and check the machine hardware clock. (man hwclock)

Comment: no. I am unable to set the date with either ntpdate or date

Answer (score 1):

Try running ntpdate on an unprivileged port (in case you are running ntpd), otherwise it will refuse make any changes.

```
ntpdate -u ntp0.cs.mu.oz.au
```

Comment: no dice. still no changes

Answer (score 1):

Try by this procedure:

**Stop** the **ntpd** service first:

```
service ntpd stop
```

Now **update** the local time

```
ntpdate "server name"
```

and after this **start the service:**

```
service ntdp start
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you given it time? Generally ntp will slowly adjust the time so when you look at logs things still make sense, and applications don't get messed up.  This is called slewing, you can read about it in 'man ntpdate' or [RFC 1305](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1305.html).

> "Time adjustments are made by ntpdate in one of two ways. If ntpdate
>   determines the clock is in error more
>   than 0.5 second it will simply step
>   the time by calling the system 
>   settimeofday()  rou‐
>              tine. If the error is less than 0.5 seconds, it will slew the
>   time by calling the system adjtime()
>   routine. The latter technique is less
>   disruptive and more accurate when the
>   error is small, and
>              works quite well when ntpdate is run by cron every hour or
>   two."

Comment: With date are you running it as root?

Comment: yep, eveything is run as root.

Comment: How long should it take? It doesn't appear to have changed in the last .5 hour. I'm still seeing the same offset 318.9... secs